# Electrons in methane

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrons, covalent-compounds

Why does a molecule of methane have 10 electrons?

I used to think that the number of electrons in methane were 8 in number but it turns out that there are 10 in number but i dont know why.
Please help
Regards

Comment: The core 1s electrons of carbon aren't depicted in the dot cross diagram.

Answer (score 3):

Methane, CH₄ has an atom of C and 4 atoms of H.

Looking at the structure of CH₄, there are 4 sigma bonds present. A sigma bond is a type of covalent bond. Each covalent bond represents a pair of electrons shared between two atoms.

This gives us 8 electrons; however one must realize that there is a pair of electrons from 1s² orbital (of the Carbon atom) which is **not** participating in any form of bonding. Hence the total 10 electrons present in a molecule of CH₄.

Another simple way to know the total number of electrons is to know the atomic numbers of the individual atoms (6 for carbon, and 1 for each hydrogen), so 6 + 1*4 = 10 electrons.
Now check the formal charge present on the molecule (in this case it is 0, CH₄ is electrically neutral - if a positive charge 'x' is found, subtract 'x' from 10 & if a negative charge 'y' is found, add 'y' to 10. Again, a total of 10 electrons is found.

Comment: I regret writing this down lol. @user198885 do see the tour: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour